# c++ singly linked list (using structures), something's wrong with insertion

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to insert elements into singly linked list based on their strings,(function strcmp is to put them into right place).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct list
{
    int num;
    char* word;
    list* next;
};
list* head;
void insert(int number,char* txt){
    list* ptr,*tmp;
        ptr=head;
    list* newlist=new list;
    newlist->num=number;
    newlist->next=NULL;
    //newlist->word= new char(strlen(txt)+1);
    newlist->word=txt;
    if(head==NULL){
        head=newlist;
        newlist->next=NULL;
    }
    else while(ptr!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(txt,ptr->word)>=0){
                if(ptr->next!=NULL && strcmp(txt,ptr->next->word)<=0)
            {
                tmp=ptr->next;
                ptr->next=newlist;
                newlist->next=tmp;
                break;
            }
                else if(ptr->next!=NULL && strcmp(txt,ptr->next->word)>0)
                    ptr=ptr->next;
                else
                 {
                    //next is empty
                    ptr->next=newlist;
                    break;
                 }
    }
            else{
                //txt mniejszy niz w 1szym elemencie
                newlist->next=head;
                head=newlist;
                break;
            }
            return;
    }
}

void print(){
    list *druk;
    druk=head;
    while(druk!=NULL){
        cout<<"txt: "<<druk->word<<" | "<<"num: "<<druk->num<<endl;
        druk=druk->next;
    }
    return;
}

int main(){

    head=NULL;

    insert(242,"Szulasdj"); 
    insert(32,"aab");
    insert(32,"aab");
    insert(14,"aaa");
    insert(85,"bbb");
    insert(5,"aac");
    insert(3,"ccc");
    insert(4,"cdc");
    insert(2,"ccd");

    print();
    cout << endl << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and I cannot figure out why it doesn't print all elements I inserted. If you could tell me where my mistake lies I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There are many fundamental problems here.  For one thing, every time you call `insert`, it generates a new list object which then leads to a memory leak.

Comment: could your explain more precisely? Also how can I fix it? Besides it is working fine, after I followed twain249's advise.

Answer (score 1):

Move the return outside of the while loop. If you get into the case where you move the pointer you have to go through the while loop again and that return exits the method before you do that.